# SwiftUI NavigationLink never releases memory

Tags: ios, swiftui, instruments

Take the most basic example app with two screens in a `NavigationView`:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        NavigationLink(destination: SubView()) {
          Text("Go to screen 2")
        }
      }
      .navigationBarTitle("Screen 1", displayMode: .inline)
    }
  }
}

struct SubView: View {
  var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!")
      .navigationBarTitle("Screen 2", displayMode: .inline)
  }
}
```

If you go to screen 2 and press the back button to go back to screen 1, `SubView` is never released. If you go back and forth multiple times, there will be multiple instances of `SubView` alive. This feels like a huge problem / memory leak, seems weird it behaves like this by default. Is there a workaround?

Comment: What do you mean by `release` for `struct`?

Comment: I mean when you profile the app and look at the SwiftUI Instrument, there are multiple instances alive if you go back and forth a few times. The instances are never released from memory, like if there is a retain cycle.

Comment: NavigationView is full of bugs. @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404725/why-does-my-swiftui-app-crash-when-navigating-backwards-after-placing-a-navigat

Comment: @KevinRenskers did you find any solutions?

Comment: No, I didn't. :(

Comment: Have your tried `NavigationStack` / `NavigationSplitView` instead?

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue on iOS 16.4 beta